# How to stop open ssh ask connection when i push with git bash

Tags: bash, ssh, git, push, open

[image]

I don't understand why git is asking me to connect to open ssh. I re-installed git a few times and did other manipulation and found nothing. I also search the internet and no one has the same problem.

The others can enter my project and push stock but I can't because of the open ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the title bar of the window, this is actually asking for an HTTPS username, not an SSH username, if you look at the URL.  This is because Git is using the `ssh-askpass` command to prompt for a username and password for HTTPS.

Git for Windows configures this behavior by default because many users on Windows use graphical programs to invoke Git, not a terminal.  Therefore, trying to prompt on the terminal would silently fail for many users without a helpful error message.  `ssh-askpass` is already shipped with Git for Windows and can be used for prompting in a graphical way without any modifications to Git.

If you'd rather be prompted on the terminal, you can unset the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable, and Git will prompt you at the terminal instead.  Additionally, if you use a credential manager, Git will store your username and password for you so you need not enter it a second time, and then you won't be prompted at all.

Comment: Can you send me the tuto for do that?

Comment: The tutorial for unsetting `GIT_ASKPASS` or for using a credential helper?  The former means to type `unset GIT_ASKPASS` or put in in your `~/.bashrc`, and the latter is adequately covered with appropriate answers on StackOverflow if you search.

Answer (score 0):

### HTTPS:

If you use https you can try 'git config credential.helper store'
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Using https it is default to prompt for user credentials.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#git-authentication-methods

### SSH:

For SSH you might need to add a ssh key to your account on the server side.
And if you don't have a key pair you must create one. (be careful not overwrite already existing one if you have).

If you use GitLab or GitHub you can find guides here.
GitLab:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account

GitHub:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: I'm with GitLab and I just don't want ssh key. that is'nt what I need :s

Comment: Are you using https or ssh? If you use https it is expected behavior and then you can try save the user credentials in git https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store.